# codeigniter validate numbers and decimals

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to validate both numbers and decimal values using codeigniter validations class?

Coz i need to give the user to enter either a number or a decimal value. `Eg: 10 or 1.5 or 30.45`

In codeigniter validation class it allows to either validate a number or decimal separately.

Can someone tell me how can this validation be done in codeigniter?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('weight', 'Weight', 'required|trim|callback_weight_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function weight_check($val)
    {
        if (!is_int($val) && !is_float($val)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('weight_check', 'The {field} field must be number or decimal.');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong. it should be !is_int($val) && !is_float($val). If you don't change it all floats will fail

Comment: @MdAshrafulIslam It is fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: @Tpjoka Your condition is still wrong. Because I have checked it again. Sorry my last condition was wrong too. Because both !is_int and !is_float fail when argument is "10.00". is_float works when argument is a number. But in this case, the argument is a string. It fails on most case. Use !filter_var($val, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) istead. No need to do that for integer too because it automatically validates integers.

Comment: No. Check with value "10.00" it fails.

Comment: Because it is string. Question required int or float condition. However, this is 3 years old answer and with your help it is fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't notice it was 3 years old. You are still very active.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building your own callback or use the regex_match rule to do it like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cost', 'Cost', array('trim','required','min_length[1]','regex_match[/(^\d+|^\d+[.]\d+)+$/]'));
```

You have to use the array way to set the rules because the regex rule uses a pipe ( | ).